# SPARQL delete statement

Tags: sparql

I am trying to delete some triples using a SPARQL query.

```
delete ?s ?p ?o {<http://www.example.org/test/unit213> ?p ?o.
            ?s ?p ?o}
```

I get the following error:

> Executing query failed: MALFORMED QUERY: Parse error: unexpected terminal varname (value: ?s). Expected terminals: ({ qname qname_ns q_iri_ref from data).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap those triples in the delete:

```
delete { ?s ?p ?o } ...
```

Comment: OK, it works now, but I have another problem: I get `No result`, although `http://www.example.org/test/unit213` is a valid URI, copied character-by-character from the store. Why is such a thng happening?

Comment: Well that's another question, but try 1) does the delete work as a query (i.e. `SELECT ...match...`)? 2) does the copied uri have a trailing / or #? 3) is the data in a named graph?

Comment: I have posted a new question here:[here][1]. As for your ideas: 1)I do not know how to test that query; 2)there is no trailing / or #; 3) the data is in a so-called repository. is it a synonym with graph?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987825/sparql-no-result-found-on-delete

Comment: And you forgot the WHERE. `DELETE { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { <http://www.example.org/test/unit213> ?p ?o. 
?s ?p ?o }`