# No result found on delete

Tags: sparql

I have the following delete statement:

```
delete {?s ?p ?o} {<http://www.example.org/test/unit213> ?p ?o.
        ?s ?p ?o}
```

The URI `http://www.example.org/test/unit213` is valid, since I get on select, among others,

```
<http://www.example.org/test/unit213>   rdf:type <http://www.example.org/test/unit>
```

Still, I get the following result:

```
No result
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably correct, SPARQL Update operations aren't supposed to return any results.

By the way, I would discourage that style of Update without the WHERE keyword, it's very easy to misread.

- Steve

Comment: But still, nothing is deleted. I can still see that URI after a `select` statement. How would you suggest writing the delete statement? Could you please provide an example based on the information above?

Comment: I am sorry. There has been a mistake. The delete statement actually DOES work. Thank you!