# SPARQL DELETE in 4store

Tags: sparql, 4store

I'm trying to delete a few triples from my triple store but, unfortunately, I can't even get this simple query to work:

```
WITH <GRAPH> DELETE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
} WHERE {
  <URI> <PREDICATE> ?s .
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

I just want to delete all triples that belong to a subject which is itself connected to the URI I have (with the predicate I have).  The WHERE statement in a SELECT query gives me all the solutions that I want to be deleted.

#### EDIT

Ok, so I kept playing around with it, and for some reason, this works:

```
WITH <GRAPH> DELETE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
} WHERE {
  <URI> <PREDICATE> ?s .
  {?s ?p ?o .} UNION {?x ?y ?z}
}
```

Is this really supposed to work like that or is my triple store faulty? (I'm using 4store.)

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?  Is there a syntax error?  Is the update "successful" but doesn't do what you want (e.g., it runs, but doesn't delete anything?

Comment: yea it runs without error, but doesnt delete anything

Comment: Thanks for the update.  What results do you get if just run the corresponding select, i.e., `WITH <GRAPH> SELECT * WHERE { <URI> <PREDICATE> ?s . ?s ?p ?o . }`, since you mentioned that it works? An example in [3.1.3 DELETE/INSERT](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert) says that `WITH <g1> DELETE { a b c } INSERT { x y z } WHERE { ... }` is equivalent to `DELETE { GRAPH <g1> { a b c } } INSERT { GRAPH <g1> { x y z } } USING <g1> WHERE { ... }`.  What happens if you use the longer form, changing `WITH <GRAPH>` inside to `GRAPH <GRAPH> { ... }`?

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned that before... I also tried that, and it gives me the same results (none :D). Running the select query gives me exactly the triples i want to delete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SPARQL no result found on delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987825/sparql-no-result-found-on-delete)